# coding of the trial software

Tags: c, trial

in the net I can find a lot of programs which give You opportunity to use program for 30 days for free and after your program is just stuck, my question is how can I code such behaviour of the program that I write, how can I be sure that noone will hack it? thanks in advance for any link and explanation

```
P.S let's assume that my program is written on c++, what technology can I use?
```

Comment: This question as posed is far too vague to answer properly - you haven't specified, among other things, what technologies you're actually using. Further, a brief search of this website (beginning with the column of Related questions that appears to the right of this one) reveals many, many possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Write the software so that it will expire in 30 days after its installed, and offer a pay version that does not

2) Same as above but offer up keys that can remove the restriction

You could validate the install date/license via a webservice (thats how linqpad does it)

As far as not being hacked... good luck, pretty much anything you come up with can be hacked if someone has the time and determination to do it